# XSLT xsl value of select= element[@attribute='$variable'] returns empty

Tags: xml, variables, xslt

I know the question has been answered already multiple times but for some reason doesn't work for me.
So what I want to achieve is to output the content of an element by using it's attribute value to access it but instead of declaring a specific value for the attribute like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="title[@attribute='value']"/>
```

This works for my code but I want  to use a variable like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="title[@attribute='$variable']"/>
```

but no matter what I do or the different ways I try it 
such as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//title[@attribute='$variable']"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="//title[@attribute= $variable]"/>
```

doesn't ouptut anything and I don't get any errors from saxon so I have no idea whats going on.

---

**xml file**

```
  <root>
   <documentname>
      <element>text</element>
        .
        .
      <element1 atributename1="VALUE1">text</element1>
        .
        .
      <element95 atributename1="value1"  secondatribute="0001"/>
         .
         .
     </documentname>
    </root>
```

**xsl file**

```
    <xsl:template match="element95 ">
       <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@atributename1">      
        <xsl:variable name="keyb" select="substring(@secondatribute,1,4)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="keyval" select="substring(@atributename1, 0,6)" />
        <xsl:variable name="keyc">
        <xsl:value-of select="'upper-case($keyval)'"/></xsl:variable>
        <a href="#{$keyc}"><xsl:value-of select="($keyb)"/>.0(<xsl:value-of select="//element1 [@atributename1=($keyc)]"/>)</a> 
   </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
```

**Output :**

```
1.0()
```

**desired ouput:**

```
1.0(text)
```

Comment: None of these compile for me,  `]` is missing.

Comment: Can you please include a minimal XSL stylesheet and a test document that produces this problem?

Comment: @Eugenios your last snippet looks fine, so it is impossible to tell what was wrong without being able to see minimal but complete example demonstrating the problem

Comment: @Eugenios You got blank output because `$keyc` value is set to literal string `'upper-case($keyval)'`; there is no `@atributename1` match `$keyc` value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues are down to string literals

```
<xsl:value-of select="//title[@attribute='$variable']"/>
```

is saying "i want to value of the attribute to be the actual string '$variable'"
so you want to use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//title[@attribute= $variable]"/>
```

However you have also made this mistake when setting the variable:

```
     <xsl:variable name="keyc">
    <xsl:value-of select="'upper-case($keyval)'"/></xsl:variable>
```

use:

```
        <xsl:variable name="keyc">
    <xsl:value-of select="upper-case($keyval)"/></xsl:variable>
```

or more readable

```
 <xsl:variable name="keyc" select="upper-case($keyval)"/>
```

And read-up on string handling and expansion in xslt generally.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems with your XSL codes :

- `$keyc` variable was set to literal string `'upper-case($keyval)'`. Remove the single-quotes to make it recognized as XPath expression and be evaluated properly.
- `substring(@atributename1, 0,6)` in your demo returns `'value'`. It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve here, but this definitely causes `//element1[@atributename1=($keyc)]` to find no match later on, because there is no `atributename1` with value equals `'value'` in the XML sample. You want to either set `substring()` parameter to a higher length, or use `substring()` of the same length when comparing `@atributename1` with `$keyc`.